# Prove without using absurd, if $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R_+^*}: x+y+z<\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z , xyz>1\implies x \neq 1, y \neq 1, z\neq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

My solution using proof by contradiction:

Let $x=1$, and $1+y+z<1+\frac1y+\frac1z$, and $yz>1\Rightarrow y+z<\frac{y+z}{yz} \Rightarrow$ positivity of $y$ and $z$ gives us $ 1<\frac1{yz}\Rightarrow yz<1$ which is not. Because of symmetry, $y=1$ or $z=1$ leads to contradiction too. So we are done.

Is there any other solution without using proof by contradiction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 2):

$$(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$$ $$ =1-x-y-z+xy+yz+zx-xyz$$ $$=1-x-y-z+xyz(\frac 1  x +\frac  1 y +\frac 1 z)-xyz$$ $$> (1-x-y-z) (1-xyz)$$ Finally, $xyz>1$ implies that $x+y+z >1$ too. (Because at least one of $x,y,z$ must be greater than $1$.  Hence $$(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)>0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed similarly as in your calculation to obtain a direct proof:
$$
 x + y + z < \frac 1x + \frac 1y + \frac 1z = \frac 1x + \frac{y+z}{yz}
< \frac 1x + x(y+z)
$$
implies
$$
0 < (x-1)(y+z) - \frac{x^2-1}{x} = (x-1)\left( y+z - \frac{x+1}{x}\right)
$$
and therefore $x-1 \ne 0$.

By symmetry, $y-1$ and $z-1$ are non-zero as well.